# #define in #define; what happens in the preprocessor?

Tags: c-preprocessor, preprocessor-directive

If I have:

```
#define X 5
#define Y X
```

what happens in the preprocessor for that kind of thing?
Is it going through the whole file and changes every X to 5,
then comes back up to the next define and then changes every Y to 5 (because in the previous iteration Y got 5) ?

Comment: Did you try it? It shouldn't take more than half a minute. What happened?

Comment: compile your code with gcc -E and you can see what kind of code that preprocessor generate

Answer (score 6):

The C standard has a special terminology for how macros are expanded.

Macro names are, in effect, stored in a big table of "all macros defined at this time".  Each table entry "macro name" on the left (and any arguments in the middle) and "expansion token-stream" on the right.

When a macro is to be expanded (because it occurs in some non-preprocessor line, or in a position in a preprocessor line in which it must be expanded -- e.g., you can `#define STDIO <stdio.h>` and then `#include STDIO`), the table entry is "painted blue", and then the replacement token-stream is read (with argument expansion as also dictated by the standard).

If the replacement token-stream contains the original macro name, it no longer matches, because the "blue paint" covers up the name.

When the replacement token-stream has been fully handled, the "blue paint" is removed, re-exposing the name.

Thus:

```
#define X 5
```

adds `X`: (no arguments), `5` to the table.

Then:

```
#define Y X
```

adds: `Y`: (no arguments), `X` to the table.

Somewhere later in the file, you might have an occurrence of the token `Y`.  Assuming neither of the above have been `#undef`ed (removed from the table), the compiler must first "paint the table entry for `Y` blue" and replace the token `Y` with the token `X`.

Next, the compiler must "paint the table entry for `X` blue" and replace the token `X` with the token `5`.

The token `5` is not a preprocessor macro name (it can't be by definition) so the token `5` passes beyond the reach of the preprocessing phase.  Now the "blue paint" is removed from the `X` table entry, as that's done; and then the "blue paint" is removed from the `Y` entry, which is also done.

---

If you were to write instead:

```
#define Y Y, Y, Y, the letter is called Y!
```

then the sequence, on encountering a later token `Y`, would be:

1. paint entry for `Y` blue
2. drop in replacement token sequence: `Y` `,` `Y` `,` `Y` `,` `the` `letter` `is` `called` `Y` `!`
3. check each replacement token in the table -- since `Y` is painted blue those don't match, and `,` cannot match, so those are all passed on to the rest of the compiler; `the`, `letter`, `is`, and `called` must be checked but are probably not in the table and hence passed on; `Y` is still painted blue so does not match and is passed on, and `!` cannot match and is passed on.
4. remove blue paint, restoring the expansion