# Using boost preprocessor for token comparison

Tags: c++, boost, macros, boost-preprocessor

I found a [page](https://github.com/pfultz2/Cloak/wiki/C-Preprocessor-tricks,-tips,-and-idioms) that it is explained how identifier-token comparison can be implemented using c preprocessor directives. This could be done by some macros like this:

```
#define COMPARE_foo(x) x
#define COMPARE_bar(x) x
#define PRIMITIVE_COMPARE(x, y) IS_PAREN \
 ( \
 COMPARE_ ## x ( COMPARE_ ## y) (())  \
 )

PRIMITIVE_COMPARE(foo, bar) // expands to 0
PRIMITIVE_COMPARE(bar, bar) // expands to 1
```

Which `IS_PAREN` checks that it is completely expanded or not(which occurs just when two macros are different because of [painting blue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20459266/define-in-define-what-happpens-in-preprocessor)).

Now I am looking for a similar command in Boost Preprocessor. I want to have a list of accepted types of a macro and if the macro called with one of this type it expands to what it must otherwise it does not anything.  My pseudo code is something like this:

```
#define ACCEPTED_TYPE (float)(int)(string)
#define Macro(x) // If one of accepted type do a otherwise do nothing
```

If boost preprocessor has not the exact solution what is your suggestion to make implementation easier.

Comment: "Painting blue" is not a common term. The trick works because applying the macro to itself, in this particular way, creates a recursive macro expansion which is skipped because macro recursion is forbidden. Anyway, it might be better to state your specific problem first, not last, and to elaborate it further. Restricting yourself to the method in the linked blog-post would be an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info).

Comment: If you don't need the list of `ACCEPTED_TYPE`s to vary easily, and you are using a modern enough compiler and Boost 1.60 (that's a lot of "if"s), [this](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/45qblp9HrBRzTwW0) could work, but if your use case is at all similar to what I've done there, there is a better approach using template specializations.

Comment: I don't think this is in Boost quite yet, but from what I recall, [VMD](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/master/libs/vmd/doc/html/index.html) might help you a lot.

Comment: @Potatoswatter Thanks for your advice. I will ask question more clear in future. But I think [blue painted](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Painted_blue) is a term use in C Standard too.

Comment: @chris It's in Boost since 1.60.

Comment: @cv_and_he, Oh, I'm not sure if I caught that release. Thanks.

Comment: @MohsenTamiz The word "blue" does not occur in the C or C++ standards, and this is the first I've encountered the phrase. Wikipedia is very confused to say that there was a "1972 C standard;" standardization occurred in the 1980s. (Ah, haha, it's on page 1972 of the linked book.) Still, thanks for the link.

Comment: @cv_and_he As you said this works very well when types are known in compile time. But if I have a template class which a user of my library can define it with different type, could I let the user register its new type and I do the same thing for the new template type?